# How do I start Orange on Linux

Tags: orange

I installed Orange on Ubuntu Linux via `conda install orange3`, as described in the Orange documentation.

I see the package installed in Anaconda3 / pkgs directory however there is not desktop icon nor can I find Orange via Window start.

Comment: Try `python -m Orange.canvas`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I am assuming that you are using Anaconda Navigator, and are trying to use Orange Canvas (the GUI method)

If the package has been installed correctly (from within Anaconda, using the Environments tab) you will see the following when opening Anaconda Navigator:

[image: Orange in Anaconda]

So, there is not a Windows desktop or start-menu icon; instead launch Orange from Anaconda Navigator.

If you have instead only installed **the biolabas Orange python library, 'Orange3'**, you will only be able to access the functions via a python programming shell by calling:

> import Orange3

Comment: I think Orange3 can also be run with: `python -m Orange.canvas`.

Comment: ...or orange-canvas command, depending on operating system you use.